# return key of array if value is present PHP

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

What is the fastest way to check if a variable is present in an array as its value and return the key of it?

Example:

```
$myArray = [ "test" => 1, "test2" = 2, "test3" = 3];

$var = [1,6,7,8,9];
```

What I need is `if($var is in $myArray) return (in this case)` "test".

Is this possible without doing two loops?
Are there any functions like `in_array()` that returns the key of the value if found?

Comment: use array_search()

Comment: @Dinidu When editing, also remove content like: "Hi", "Thanks" etc.

Comment: array_search is what i was looking for, Thank you. @jothi

Comment: `var_dump( array_keys(array_intersect($myArray, $var)) );`

Comment: @hjpotter92 I also thought of this, But my opinion was to preserve the originality of the post. I will remove them in future edits. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `array_search`

```
foreach($var as $value)
{
    $key = array_search($value, $myArray);
    if($key === FALSE)
    {
        //Not Found
    }
    else
    {
        //$key contains the index you want
    }
}
```

Be careful, if the value is not found the function will return `false` but it may also return a value that can be treated the same way as false, like 0 on a zero based array so it's best to use the `===` operator as shown in my example above

Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) for more

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_search`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful

**Example:**

```
$myArray = ["test" => 1, "test2" = 2, "test3" = 3];
$var = [1, 6, 7, 8, 9];

foreach ($var as $i) {
    $index = array_search($i, $myArray);

    if ($index === false) {
        echo "$i is not in the array";
    } else {
        echo "$i is in the array at index $index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

//The values in this arrays contains the values that should exist in the data array
$var = [1,6,7,8,9];

$myArray = [ "test" => 1, "test2" = 2, "test3" = 3];

if(count(array_intersect_key(array_flip($myArray), $var)) === count($var)) {
    //All required values exist!              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dnt need to use 2loops.
     use 'array_intersect'.
     'array_intersect' will return common value present in both the sets of array
    
if you want Match keys then use  'array_intersect_key'

```
$myArray = array("test" => 1, "test2" => 2, "test3" => 3);

$var = array(1,6,7,8,9);
$intersect=array_intersect($myArray, $var);

var_dump($intersect);
```

output:

```
array(1) {
    ["test"]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 1):

use `array_search()`

```
foreach ($var as $row) 
{
   $index_val = array_search($row, $myArray);

  if ($index_val === false) 
  {

     echo "not present";
  } 
 else
 {
     echo "presented";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
dont missed => wehere "test2" & "test3"
    $myArray = ["test" => 1, "test2" => 2, "test3" => 3];
    $var = [1, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    foreach ($var as $i) {
        $index = array_search($i, $myArray);

        if ($index === false) {
            echo "$i is not in the array";
        } else {
            echo "$i is in the array at index $index";
        }
    }
    ?>
```